# External List in Datasheet View

Tags: 2010, datasheet, view

How to I get an External List in Datasheet View? 
I have a List, whereby I have Looked up a Column from an External List. The column appears as readonly in Datasheet View, but behaves normally using the normal view.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the limitations of an external list; there is no way to get a datasheet view with the built in functionality of SharePoint.

Other limitations are quite well ennumerated on [this blog post](http://kdkadyan.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/bcs-and-external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint-2010/). As you can see, there are quite a few of them and it is worth bearing these in mind when designing solutions with the Business Connectivity Services.

Comment: Any possibility of using Javascript to solve?

Comment: I don't think so, with the standard external list. There is a third party web part available from [layer2](http://www.layer2.de/en/products/pages/sharepoint-business-data-list-connector.aspx) that claims to allow it, but I haven't tried this out yet.